# Why is there a date.today() but no time.now() in the datetime module?

Tags: python, datetime

I am editing some Python and ran across this inconsistency in the datetime module.
For the current date I just need:

```
from datetime import date
todaysDate = date.today()
if todaysDate > date( 2020,4,4 ) :
...
```

but for time:

```
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import time
nowTime = datetime.now().time()
if nowTime > time( 17,15,0 ) :
...
```

Any rational for not having a "now()" method (or whatever name) in the datetime.time object?  This would be much cleaner:

```
from datetime import time
nowTime = time.now()
if nowTime > time( 17,15,0 ) :
...
```

PS: The time module is not an option at this point

Comment: There is no datetime.date.now() either. "Now" includes date and time together, so there is datetime.datetime.now().

Comment: I know there is no date.now() (and that datetime.now() includes date and time).  For date, it is date.today().I honestly don't care about the name, just that it exists.  It (a 'getCurrentDate') exists for the date object, but it (a 'getCurrentTime') does not for the time object.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect, but am not certain, that the reason there is no `datetime.time.now()` is that the type `datetime.time` does not represent a point in time -- rather it represents a time of day. So, while it might sometimes be a slight convenience to be able to get the current time of day without getting the current date, it's not an essential operation.

I suspect GvR would not share your assessment that removing `.time()` makes the code "much" cleaner. I'd assess it "very slightly" cleaner, and as against that you'd duplicate two functions on `time` that are on `datetime`, since someone would want `utcnow()`. And someone else would want `time.now()` to take the optional timezone argument.

Comment: date.utctoday() does not exist, yet it could be a different date depending on time zone.  Similarly, I would not add time.utcnow().

Comment: I understand your point, but I can't see this as a strong enough reason to make time different than date (which is my main point).

Comment: @Frigg: agreed, I don't think the interface duplication is the reason. I just raised it because you mentioned cleanliness.